# Cycles modifier without cutting off

Tags: animation

[image]
The animation in the picture has a cycles modifier that ends after 85 frames, but at the end the curve goes back to the starting position. How or is there a way to make it not go back to it's starting position, or do I have to add an extra keyframe that makes it stay there at the end?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the cycles that restricts the frame range ends at 85, add another modifier Limits and set Max X to 85 or 84.

Comment: didnt work but it's fine cus i decided to copy and paste the keyframes